# How can I use vitess on production?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, replication, sharding, vitess

I have two kubernetes cluster and I want to make master-master replication for Mysql database. As I read vitess documentation, that is convenient, but I don't know how to do that?
the data is more than 500G in mysql and maybe need sharding. how can I use vitess as Mysql cluster to have zero down time on database layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vitess does not support master-master replication: https://vitess.io/docs/overview/scalability-philosophy/#no-active-active-replication

If zero downtime is your primary concern, then I recommend looking to Percona Xtradb Cluster or Mysql Group Replication, but these require very reliable network between cluster nodes and can easily cause more issues then solve if used incorrectly.